# Добавление экземпляра класса в список

Tags: python-3.x

Предположим есть кусок кода где: класс Word и пара классов Noun и Verb которые наследуются от первого.
При попытке компиляции, в момент добавления первого экземпляра Noun("собака"), возникает ошибка: `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
class Word:  
    def __init__(self, text):  
        self.text = text

class Noun(Word):
    def __init__(self):
        self.part = "существительное"

class Verb(Word):
    def __init__(self):
        self.part = "глагол"

words = []
words.append(Noun("собака"))
words.append(Verb("ела"))
words.append(Noun("колбасу"))
```

Помогите пожалуйста - не соображу что делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Word:  
    def __init__(self, text):  
        self.text = text

class Noun(Word):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.part = "существительное"
        super().__init__(text)


class Verb(Word):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.part = "глагол"
        super().__init__(text)

words = []
words.append(Noun("собака"))
words.append(Verb("ела"))
words.append(Noun("колбасу"))
```

В классах наследниках в методе инициализации класса вы не указали параметра`text`, которому хотите присваивать значения текста.

Интерпритатор на команде `Noun("собака")` видит метод `__init__` класса `Noun` и не находит в нем второго параметра(первый всегда `self`).

Answer (score 3):

При вызове `Noun("собака")` вызывается `__init__` класса `Noun`
Он не принимает переменных:

```
def __init__(self):
```

Во вторых, при вызове `Noun("собака")` `__init__` класса `Word` не будет вызван.
Для его вызова:

```
super().__init__(text)
```

Итого твой код должен быть:

```
class Word:  
    def __init__(self, text):  
        self.text = text

class Noun(Word):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.part = "существительное"

class Verb(Word):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__(text)
        self.part = "глагол"

words = []
words.append(Noun("собака"))
words.append(Verb("ела"))
words.append(Noun("колбасу"))
```

Comment: Слона не заметил. Спасибо большое. Аж стыдно, до чего нелепо.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Word:  
    def __init__(self, text):  
        self.text = text

class Noun(Word):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.part = text

class Verb(Word):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.part = text

words = []
words.append(Noun("собака"))
words.append(Verb("ела"))
words.append(Noun("колбасу"))


print(*words, sep="\n")    
print(*[cl.part  for cl in words])
```

`<__main__.Noun object at 0x0000000002985EB8>
<__main__.Verb object at 0x0000000002998B38>
<__main__.Noun object at 0x0000000002998B70>
собака ела колбасу`